# How to send keyboard events to a QEMU guest programmatically?

Tags: c, qemu

Let's say I have some preexisting iso(for example, alpine linux). And I start it with

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cdrom alpine-virt-3.5.0-x86_64.iso
```

At this point, I'd like to perform some setup(and avoid doing it manually).

One way to do this, I guess, is by using xdotool, but it would be not very convenient because an entire Xorg session will be busy with one QEMU guest.

Maybe there is a better way? Can it be done via QMP or QEMU C API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way would be to have the console on serial and tell qemu to redirect the serial port of the guest system to stdio of the host:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cdrom alpine-virt-3.5.0-x86_64.iso -append "console=ttyS0" -serial stdio
```

Then you can try to do your custom setup on stdio of the qemu-process. Alternatively you also can use a listen socket and connect to it: `-serial tcp::12345,server`

Ultimatively you should strive to use possible existing mechanisms which are meant for doing automatic setup, as for example the preseed-files for Debian GNU/Linux and the like, since doing it this way is probably quite error-prone.

Comment: I'm also trying to automate actions on qemu VM through stdio, but with `-nographic` option. Adding `-append "console=ttyS0" -serial stdio` from your answer produces error: `"cannot use stdio by multiple character devices"`. But then I've also added `-monitor none`, and now everything works properly.